# Private repo getting downloaded from docker.hub

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, dockerhub

I am trying to push something into hub.docker.com into private repository when I pushed the changes to private repo and after some time if check the status it surprised me as pull/downloads counts keep increment. Can anyone pulled private repo data from hub.docker.com ?

```
docker build -t username/<repo>:latest .

docker push username/<repo>:latest
```

those two command I am using.
Thanks

Comment: It requires docker hub credentials to pull from private repositories on docker hub.

Comment: If you pushed data into private repo will anyone able to download/pull ?

Comment: No. You can try it on your own system as well, by first doing a `docker logout` and then trying to pull the image.